# Is C and C++ client side? or server side?

Tags: c++, c, client-side, server-side

Is c and C++ server side programming languages like java? if yes how like in java we have apllets for client side and jsp and servelets for server side.

Comment: Both are Side by Side.

Comment: C++ is a programming language that doesn't know anything about servers or clients. You can use it to implement both.

Comment: u mean c and c++ is both client and server side

Comment: @ik024 Or neither. The classification doesn't make any sense. It is like saying "C++ is a counting apples *and* modifying elephants language".

Comment: You can write *a server* in C/C++. They are general purpose languages.

Comment: -1 because `This question does not show any research effort`. edit: -1 removed. But for the future: On Stack Overflow it is common practice to describe what you have tried and found out, and why this does not help you in some specific problem.

Comment: This is kind of like asking: "I can assemble computers using a screwdriver tool. Are the computers assembled by me, with my screwdriver, clients or servers?" Well, you made them, you tell us. The screwdriver you used doesn't specify what the result will be. And you can also use your screwdriver for a lot of other things than assembling computers.

Comment: thats a nice way of puttin it :)

Comment: @ Yuushi, phresnel, Lundin, Balog Pal, PlasmaHH okay! will keep in mind about this in future :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both C and C++ are languages that allow the programmer to write code for almost any purpose, from low level to higher levels. A large number of other languages and libraries are implemented using either C or C++ (or a combination thereof).

You can probably implement almost anything using C and C++, and it's not strictly for (or not for) anything in particular.

Is it the best language for X? Is it "not the best language" for X? [in X, we can take almost any programming task]. That would largely depend on how you define "best".

C and C++ can take quite some time to develop in, and especially for beginners that aren't aware of some of the "pitfalls" in C and C++. But C and C++, especially C++, is a language where some additional coding can almost build a new language that can be used to do very powerful work in just a little bit of code. So you can almost do all the things that any other language can. But that doesn't necessarily mean that it's "the best" way to achieve that goal. It may be quicker to take Python, Java or PHP to write some particular type of code. Python and PHP are specifically developed to "make it easy to write new code", where C++ is developed for efficiency and "detailed control" over what goes on.

Answer (score 1):

From the [wikipedia/C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) (presented here as bullet points):

- C++ (pronounced "see plus plus") is a statically typed, free-form, **multi-paradigm, compiled, general-purpose programming language**. It is regarded as an intermediate-level language, as it comprises both high-level and low-level language features.
- C++ is one of the most popular programming languages[5][6] and is implemented on a wide variety of hardware and operating system platforms. As an efficient compiler to native code, **its application domains include systems software, application software, device drivers, embedded software, high-performance server and client applications, and entertainment software such as video games**

Hope that helps you to understand what C++ is, what it is for!

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ don't really fit in the client-server paradigm, but within it they probably would be qualified as server-side languages. They are compiled languages, which make them hard to be used on client-side (compiler needs to know about the hardware that execute the compiled code). Java is a compiled language too but thanks to its design (compiled as bytecode which is executable by the JVM, running on the client and available for all platforms) it can be used on the client-side (it's a portable language).

Comment: `They are compiled languages, which make them hard to be used on client-side` -> No.

Comment: C and C++ can also be [compiled to WebAssembly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/C_to_wasm) in order to run on the client-side of a web application.